# How to parse list of models with Pydantic

Tags: python, pydantic

I use Pydantic to model the requests and responses to an API.

I defined a `User` class:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class User(BaseModel):
  name: str
  age: int
```

My API returns a list of users which I retrieve with `requests` and convert into a dict:

```py
users = [{"name": "user1", "age": 15}, {"name": "user2", "age": 28}]
```

How can I convert this dict to a list of `User` instances?

My solution for now is

```py
user_list = []
for user in users:
  user_list.append(User(**user))
```

Answer (score 187, accepted):

### Pydantic V1:

This is now possible using `parse_obj_as`.

```py
from pydantic import parse_obj_as

users = [
    {"name": "user1", "age": 15}, 
    {"name": "user2", "age": 28}
]

m = parse_obj_as(List[User], users)
```

### Pydantic V2:

Use [Type Adapter](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/type_adapter/).

```
from pydantic import TypeAdapter

users = [
    {"name": "user1", "age": 15}, 
    {"name": "user2", "age": 28}
]

ta = TypeAdapter(List[User])
m = ta.validate_python(users)
```

Comment: Is there a function to do reverse, i.e given List[User] converts List[dict]

Comment: @ShivKrishnaJaiswal, if you're in FastAPI, there's [`fastapi.encoders.jsonable_encoder`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/encoder/), as in `jsonable_encoder(my_user_list)`.

Comment: I got the unhappy `__root__ value is not a valid list (type=type_error.list)`

Comment: There is pydantic.json.pydantic_encoder, for those who do not want to install FastAPI for that. Cf https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/dataclasses/#json-dumping

Comment: Pydantic 2.0 update: use `TypeAdapter(List[User]).validate_python(users)`.

Moreover, if you have access to the raw JSON `bytes`/`str`, you might also want to delegate the parsing step to Pydantic (skipping the intermediate `dict` representation).
e.g. `TypeAdapter(List[User]).validate_json(json_bytes)`

Comment: parse_obj_as is already deprecated.

Answer (score 61):

To confirm and expand the previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58636633/3475543), here is an "official" answer at [pydantic-github](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/675#issuecomment-513029543) - All credits to "**dmontagu**":

> The "right" way to do this in pydantic is to make use of "Custom Root
> Types". You still need to make use of a container model:

```
class UserList(BaseModel):
    __root__: List[User]
```

but then the following will work:

```
UserList.parse_obj([
    {'id': '123', 'signup_ts': '2017-06-01 12:22', 'friends': [1, '2', b'3']},
    {'id': '456', 'signup_ts': '2017-06-02 12:22', 'friends': ['you']},
])
```

> (and will put the values inside the **root** property).
>
> Unfortunately, I think there is not good serialization support for
> this yet, so I think when you go to return the results, if you want to
> return just a list you'll still need to return UserList.**root**.
>
> I don't think there is currently a unified interface that gets you a
> serialized/unstructured version of the model that respects the
> **root_model**, but if this is what you are looking for, it could be worth building.

Comment: If you use `.json()` for a model with a custom root type, it'll root the root object (without the `'__root__': `).

Comment: Except when you use `.dict()` it will include `__root__` keys :)

Comment: To remove `__root__` key, I defined `dict` method which does `return super().dict()['__root__']`

Comment: @hshib can u share the snippet of how did it? Thanks in advance.

The ugly way I am working with is json.loads(SomeSchema.json())

Comment: In the meantime `RootModel` was added to pydantic v2 (in may), which works very similar to this example: `class UserList(RootModel): root: list[User]`. The only difference in the use is, that you can leave out the dunders. Also you get some custom behaviour of theRootModel class compared to the BaseModel, e.g. throwing an exception when a non-root field is added.

Answer (score 22):

You can try this

```
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel

class User(BaseModel):
  name: str
  age: int

class Users(BaseModel):
    users: List[User]

users = [{"name": "user1", "age": 15}, {"name": "user2", "age": 28}]
m = Users(users=users)
print(m.dict())
```

Comment: Thanks, but that returns an object with a `users` property that contains the list. I will keep it in mind if there is no way to do this, that's nicer!

Answer (score 20):

You could consider using a list comprehension along with dict unpacking to the `User` constructor

```
user_list = [
  User(**user) for user in users
]
```

Comment: I like it, pretty clean

Comment: simplest and most obvious. should be accepted answer.

Comment: FYI this method is about **2x** faster than the accepted answer. I have no idea why the other one was accepted instead lol.

Comment: @rv.kvetch can you show how you test the speed?

Comment: yes, cleanest & fastest solution. However pydantic throws 'model_attributes_type' validation error, seems pydantic expects 'users' property that contains the list. Any suggestion to make it work in pydantic as well ?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [`__root__`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#custom-root-types) Pydantic keyword:

```py
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel

class User(BaseModel):
  name: str
  age: int

class UserList(BaseModel):
  __root__: List[User]     # ⯇-- __root__
```

To build the JSON response:

```py
user1 = {"name": "user1", "age": 15}
user2 = {"name": "user2", "age": 28}

user_list = UserList(__root__=[])
user_list.__root__.append(User(**user1))
user_list.__root__.append(User(**user2))
```

Your API web framework can jsonify `user_list` to be returned as a JSON array (within the response body).

Answer (score 4):

### Pydantic V2

For adapter approach see [david-asaf's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61021183/3364871).

Another solution is to use [RootModel](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/models/#rootmodel-and-custom-root-types):

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, RootModel

class User(BaseModel):
  name: str
  age: int

class PersonList(RootModel):
    root: list[User]

users = [{"name": "user1", "age": 15}, {"name": "user2", "age": 28}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I just set in my **`models.py`** list of dict like this:

```
from django.db import models
from pydantic import BaseModel

class CustomList(BaseModel):
    data: list[dict]
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me using list comprehension:

```
user_list = [User(**user) for user in users]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another idea to simple this code if pydantic version below 1.2 that doesn't support **parse_obj_as** method.

```
user_list = []
for user in users:
  user_list.append(User(**user))
```

simple way

```
user_list = [User(**user) for user in users]
```

Answer (score 0):

> here is the pydantic model model.py

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Post_Response(BaseModel):
    name: str

class Post_Mother(BaseModel):
    status: int
    users: List[Post_Response] = []
```

> let import it into our app.py

```
from . import Post_Response, Post_Mother

response = Post_Mother(
        status=200,
        users=[Post_Response(name='user_name')],
 )
```