# How to map values from nested dict to Pydantic Model?

Tags: python, pydantic

I am trying to map a value from a nested dict/json to my Pydantic model. For me, this works well when my json/dict has a flat structure. However, I am struggling to map values from a nested structure to my Pydantic Model.

Lets assume I have a json/dict in the following format:

```
d = {
    "p_id": 1,
    "billing": {
        "first_name": "test"
    }
}
```

In addition, I have a Pydantic model with two attributes:

```
class Order(BaseModel):
    p_id: int
    pre_name: str
```

How can I map the value from the key `first_name`to my Pydantic attribute `pre_name`?

Is there an easy way instead of using a `root_validator` to parse the given structure to my flat pydantic Model?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can customize `__init__` of your model class:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

d = {
    "p_id": 1,
    "billing": {
        "first_name": "test"
    }
}


class Order(BaseModel):
    p_id: int
    pre_name: str

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs["pre_name"] = kwargs["billing"]["first_name"]
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


print(Order.parse_obj(d))  # p_id=1 pre_name='test'
```

Comment: Is this the best way to do this? or is doing this bad practice....

Comment: how to do if billing is list of items instead of object? and is this best practice?

Answer (score 3):

There's a package [PyMapMe](https://github.com/funnydman/pymapme/tree/main) for mapping models, it supports nested models as well as helping functions and context, for example:

```
from typing import Any

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from pymapme.models.mapping import MappingModel


class Person(BaseModel):
    name: str
    surname: str


class Profile(BaseModel):
    nickname: str
    person: Person


class User(MappingModel):
    nickname: str = Field(source='nickname')
    first_name: str = Field(source='person.name')
    surname: str = Field(source='person.surname')
    full_name: str = Field(source_func='_get_full_name')

    @staticmethod
    def _get_full_name(model: Profile, default: Any):
        return model.person.name + ' ' + model.person.surname


profile = Profile(nickname='baobab', person=Person(name='John', surname='Smith'))
user = User.build_from_model(profile)
print(user.dict())  # {'nickname': 'baobab', 'first_name': 'John', 'surname': 'Smith', 'full_name': 'John Smith'}
```

Or for your example, it would look like:

```
d = {
    "p_id": 1,
    "billing": {
        "first_name": "test"
    }
}


class Billing(BaseModel):
    first_name: str


class Data(BaseModel):
    p_id: int
    billing: Billing


class Order(MappingModel):
    p_id: int
    pre_name: str = Field(source='billing.first_name')


order = Order.build_from_model(Data(**d))
print(order.dict())
```

Note: I'm the author, pull requests and any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can nest pydantic models by making your lower levels another pydantic model. See as follows:

```
class MtnPayer(BaseModel):
  partyIdType: str
  partyId: str

class MtnPayment(BaseModel):
  financialTransactionId: str
  externalId: str
  amount: str
  currency: str
  payer: MtnPayer
  payerMessage: str
  payeeNote: str
  status: str
  reason: str
```

See the payer item in the second model

Answer (score 0):

You could inherit from this custom class instead of `BaseModel` (see below).

```
from collections.abc import MutableMapping
from typing import Any, Iterator

from pydantic import BaseModel


class BaseModelDict(BaseModel, MutableMapping):
    """Goodness of BaseModel and acts like a dictionary."""

    def __contains__(self, x: str) -> bool:
        return True if x in self.__dict__.keys() else False

    def __delitem__(self, x: str) -> None:
        del self.__dict__[x]

    def __getitem__(self, x: str) -> Any:
        return self.__dict__[x]

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator:
        return iter(self.__dict__)

    def __json__(self) -> dict:
        return self.__dict__

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self.__dict__)

    def __setitem__(self, key: str, value: Any) -> None:
        self.__dict__[key] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has answered the question, your Oder model has to match up with the data keys i.e.

```py
d = {
    "p_id": 1,
    "billing": {
        "first_name": "test"
    }
}

class Order(BaseModel):
    p_id: int
    billing: dict[str, str]

# Then simply

order = Order(**d)
```

should do it. From [official example](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/#pydantic-examples).

Answer (score 0):

For my future self who lands here, a better solution is to use parse_obj of pydantic v2. You can use MyModel.parse_obj(my_dict) to generate a model from a dictionary. ([documentation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#helper-functions))

**Example**:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, parse_obj_as
from typing import List

class TimeSlot(BaseModel):
    from_: str
    to: str

class DayActiveHours(BaseModel):
    days: List[str]
    time_slots: List[TimeSlot]

# Example nested dictionary
nested_data = {
    "days": ["Monday", "Tuesday"],
    "time_slots": [
        {"from_": "08:00", "to": "12:00"},
        {"from_": "13:00", "to": "17:00"}
    ]
}

# Parse the nested dictionary into Pydantic models
active_hours = DayActiveHours.parse_obj(nested_data)

# Now, you can access the parsed values using the Pydantic model attributes
print(active_hours.days)  # Output: ["Monday", "Tuesday"]
print(active_hours.time_slots)  # Output: [TimeSlot(from_='08:00', to='12:00'), TimeSlot(from_='13:00', to='17:00')]
```

Refer the solution here (pydantic v2) : [How to parse list of models with Pydantic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55762673/how-to-parse-list-of-models-with-pydantic)