# psycop2 list of dictRow to nested pydantic objects

Tags: psycopg2, fastapi, pydantic

I am working on a small Python CRUD game using `FastAPI`. For personal reasons, I don't want to use an ORM and I am using `psycop2` as a db connector and `pydantic` for schemas validation (for any CRUD operations).

**models/villages.py**

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Village(BaseModel):

    village_id: int
    name: str
    owner_id: int
    location_id: int


class UserVillages(BaseModel):

    villages: list[Village]
```

**crud/villages.py**

```
def get_villages(session: Database, user_id: str):
    sql = """
        SELECT *
        FROM villages 
        WHERE owner_id = (%s)
        """
    params = [user_id]
    records = session.select_rows_dict_cursor(sql, params)
    print(records) ## [[1, 'paris', 145, 4, 41], [3, 'milan', 16, 4, 15]]
```

Instead of printing `records`, I would like to convert all of my `dictRow` into a `Village` object and all `Villages` into a `UserVillages` village object. Would it be posible to do that without a lop of extra data structure and loops?

**I found a way to do it but it's not really efficient and there is probably build-in functions to do it **

```
def get_villages(session: Database, user_id: str):
    sql = """
        SELECT *
        FROM villages 
        WHERE owner_id = (%s)
        """
    params = [user_id]
    records = session.select_rows_dict_cursor(sql, params)
    villages = []
    for record in records:
        villages.append(
            Village(
                village_id=record[0],
                name=record[1],
                owner_id=record[2],
                location_id=record[3],
            )
        )
    return UserVillages(villages=villages)
```

Comment: Does your column names in the table match the pydantic field names?

Comment: they do, at least the ones I have selected in my query

Comment: In that case you should be able to do `return UserVillages(villages=parse_obj_as(List[Village], records))`  as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61021183/137650 `parse_obj_as` is a utility function under `pydantic`