# Pass an optional list of strings to a Pydantic-CLI - based argument parser

Tags: python, argparse, pydantic

Based on the [official pydantic-CLI docs](https://pypi.org/project/pydantic-cli/) I created the following CommandLineArguments-class from the base class "BaseModel":

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, parse_obj_as
from typing import List, Optional

class CommandLineArguments(BaseModel):
    """Command Line Arguments."""
    config_files: Optional[List[str]] = Field(
        [],
        description='Paths to the config files that should be validated',
        cli=('--config-files', ),
    )
    with_log: Optional[bool] = Field(
        False,
        description='Enable logging ouput',
        cli=('--with-log', '--no-log'),
    )
    stacktrace: Optional[bool] = Field(
        False,
        description='Enable stack trace output',
        cli=('--with-stacktrace', '--no-stacktrace'),
    )
```

In the aforementioned docs, there is a Limitations-section saying:

[image: limits on lists]

Indeed, when executing the command-line script, the `--config-files` - part *always fails since following file name(s) cannot be parsed/recognized as a list of strings*:

```
❯ python src/scripts/config_validation.py --config-files src/config/some.json --with-log --with-stacktrace


... Starting config validation script

usage: config_validation.py [--config-files CONFIG_FILES [CONFIG_FILES ...]]
                            [--with-log] [--with-stacktrace] [--help]
                            [--version]

Status (2) Failed to run command config_validation.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --config-files src/config/some.json
  File "C:\Users\username\Projects\proj-venv\lib\site-packages\pydantic_cli\__init__.py", line 481, in _runner
    pargs = parser.parse_args(args)
  File "C:\Users\username\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.7.9\lib\argparse.py", line 1758, in parse_args
    self.error(msg % ' '.join(argv))
  File "C:\Users\username\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.7.9\lib\argparse.py", line 2508, in error
    self.exit(2, _('%(prog)s: error: %(message)s\n') % args)
  File "C:\Users\username\Projects\proj-venv\lib\site-packages\pydantic_cli\argparse.py", line 75, in exit
    status, f"Status ({status}) Failed to run command {message}"
```

By contrast, with [argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753701/how-can-i-pass-a-list-as-a-command-line-argument-with-argparse) this just works out of the box with some additional parameter to be set.

Is there something I forgot or need to do differently in my implementation above?

```
config_files: Optional[List[str]] = Field(
    [],
    description='Paths to the config files that should be validated',
    cli=('--config-files', ),
)
```

---

**EDIT** (new approaches):

Based on [this question on StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55762673/how-to-parse-list-of-models-with-pydantic) and [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/675), I tried the following with no avail either:

```
from typing import List, Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from pydantic_cli import run_and_exit


class ConfigFile(BaseModel):
    config_file: str


class ConfigFiles(BaseModel):
    __root__: List[ConfigFile]


class CommandLineArguments(BaseModel):
    """Command Line Arguments."""
    config_files: Optional[ConfigFiles] = None
    with_log: Optional[bool] = Field(
        False,
        description='Enable logging ouput',
        cli=('--with-log', '--no-log'),
    )
    stacktrace: Optional[bool] = Field(
        False,
        description='Enable stack trace output',
        cli=('--with-stacktrace', '--no-stacktrace'),
    )
```