Pydantic 2 model has field composed by a list of another model
I would like to serialize the result of a SqlAlchemy query that returns more than one row (a list of rows); all my api need to return the same json (status_code, data , message, success true/false) where data is a List of the pydantic model of the given entity.
this is my following scenario:
class User(SQLModel, Model, table=True):
    # this is a sqlmodel used to deserialize the payload and to interact with db
    __tablename__ = "users"
    user_id: Optional[int] = Field(primary_key=True, default=None)
    username: str = Field(unique=True)
    email: str = Field()
    secret_code: Optional[int]
    secret_code_expiration_date: Optional[datetime]
    role_id: int = Field(foreign_key="roles.role_id")
    role: Role = Relationship(back_populates="users")

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"<User (username={self.username}, email={self.email}, role={self.role.name})>"

    @classmethod
    @field_validator("email")
    def val_email(cls, email: str):
        if not validate_email(email):
            raise ValidationError("Invalid Email format")
        return email

    @classmethod
    @field_validator("pwd")
    def validate_password(cls, pwd: str):
        if not validate_pwd(pwd):
            raise ValidationError("Invalid Password format")
        return pwd


class UserSerializer(BaseModel):
    username: str
    role: str
    functionalities: List[str]

    @classmethod
    def from_orm(cls, obj: User) -> "UserSerializer":
        return cls(
            username=obj.username,
            role=obj.role.name,
            functionalities=obj.role.functions,
        )

class UserApiResponse(ApiResponse):
    data: List[UserSerializer]


class ApiResponse:
    message: str = Field(default='')
    success: bool = Field(default=True)
    status_code: int = Field(default=200)


router = APIRouter()


@router.get(
    "/library/user/{username}", response_model=UserApiResponse
)
async def get_user_by_username(username: str):
    try:
        users = User.select_user(username=username)
    except RowNotFound:
        return {"success":False, "status_code": 404, "message": "user not found"}
    return {"data": [UserSerializer.from_orm(user) for user in users]}


is there a way to avoid the list comprehension? (doing in a different way or making Pydantic/SqlModel/FastAPi doing it for me). It seems so slow to me.

UserApiResponse can be defined as having a list of users as it's data, and you can configure from_attributes on your response model to avoid having to call from_orm manually. The speed won't have any meaningful difference though, it'll be the same in any case.

@MatsLindh you mean something like this? List[My_sql_model_for_user]
And how can I "tell" to Pydantic that I would like data to contain not all user_columns but just the ones selected in UserSerializer?

You can use a TypeAdapter in Pydantic v2 if you want to it manually, instead of defining a List as the response model for your endpoint (the metadata should probably be handled in a middleware instead of having to clutter every endpoint you're writing - we also have a mechanism for those factors already - http status codes and headers - but I digress). You can see an example of using a TypeAdapter to convert a List to a model here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61021183/137650 - by default only the columns included in your pydantic model will be included.

As you've added your example: as long as you define your UserApiResponse as allowing from_attributes in your model_config (you can set it on ApiResponse if you want to), you should be good to go as long as you return the SQLAlchemy objects directly as a list under the data key as you do. No need to convert them manually.
